# Show images in cells from array

Tags: ios, swift, cell

I have `TableViewController` and `AudioPlayerViewController`. In `TableViewController` I want to know how many tracks have been listened to. And show the image in the listened cells `TableViewController`. To detect that track have been listened I use this code in `AudioPlayerViewController`:

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
     UserDefaults.standard.set( arrayOfListened(trackIndex), forKey: "key") 
}
```

And to show image in listened cells in `TableViewController` next:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath) as! MasterViewCell

    if indexPath.row == arrayOfListened[indexPath.row] {
        cell.cellStatusImage.image = UIImage(named: "statusDone.png")
    }
                
}
```

But my app crashed. How to fix it?

Comment: Crashed *where* and *why*?

Comment: @user Also what is the crash?

Comment: @vadian index out of range - `if indexPath.row == arrayOfListened[indexPath.row]`

Comment: `arrayOfListened` contains less items than the number of rows in the table view. Use a **real** data source array.

Comment: @vadian so I need to show the picture only in those lines that the array contains.

Comment: @user there is a different number of elements between arrayOfListened and the number of the row in the tableView. In the numberOfRowsInSection use arrayOfListened.count

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get an element from the array by `indexPath.row` which probably doesn't exist. Try to use something like this:

```swift
...

guard 
    arrayOfListened.indices.contains(indexPath.row), 
    indexPath.row == arrayOfListened[indexPath.row] 
else {
    return cell
}

... your cell configuration
```

Or, if your arrayOfListened just contains song IDs, you can simply use:

```swift
if arrayOfListened.contains(indexPath.row) {
    ... your cell configuration
}
```